# If f is continuous almost everywhere, does there always exist an interval (a, b) with positive length where f is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I think Thomae's function is a counter-example:

f(x) = 0 if x is irrational, and f(x) = 1/q if x is a rational number expressed in the form p/q.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: $\mathbb 1_{\mathbb Q}$ is also a counter-example.

Comment: @elidiot No, it is not almost everywhere continuous. (It is not continuous at any point.)

Comment: Oh shame... I shouldn't be making errors like this. My bad